# Sequelize queries using Express req.query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize along with Express (REST API). What I want to be able to do is to e.g. send GET request to: `api.myapp.com/v1/posts?author_id=some-id-here&tags=tag-a,tag-b`
I would like to somehow configure in my backend code which queries are available for the user to use, and they would be translated into `where`, `include` etc. like:

```
DB.Model.findAll({
  include: [
    { model: DB.Author, as: 'author', where: { ... }},
    { model: DB.Tag, as: 'tags', where: { ... }}
  ],
});
```

My question – is there a package for this?
I was searching for a while now and have not found anything and writing those by hand seems quite tricky, especially for a newbie in NodeJS/Sequelize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no package available to meet your criteria, tbh it would be very redundant if a package/project like that exists.

> You can check this link to get started: 
>   https://github.com/saqsham/sequelize-v5.0-starter-api/

I would appreciate any kind of suggestion.